# Xamarin android get contacts with addresses

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How can I get contact with addresses?

```
  var uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.ContentUri;

        string[] projection = {
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.InterfaceConsts.Id,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FormattedAddress
        };


        var cursor = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);

        var contactList = new List<(string id, string name, string address)>();

        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            do
            {
                contactList.Add(
                    (
                        cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0])),
                        cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1])),
                        cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2]))
                    )
                );
            } while (cursor.MoveToNext());
        }
```

when i try this I get exception saying "Invalid column data1" I just want list of contact + his address

Answer (score 0):

The alias `FormattedAddress` (or `data1`) exists on the provider of:

- `content://com.android.contacts/data/phones`

So use `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri`:

```
var uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri;
string[] projection = {
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.InterfaceConsts.Id,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName,
    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FormattedAddress
};
var cursor = Application.Context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
var contactList = new List<(string id, string name, string address)>();
while (cursor.MoveToNext())
{
    contactList.Add(
        (
            cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0])),
            cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1])),
            cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[2]))
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: no exception anymore but it gives me phone number instead of FormattedAddress, any idea?

Comment: Found, because ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number and ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredPostal.FormattedAddress have the value of data1 .... still cant get contacts with addresses. please help